# Why do I keep getting 400 malformed when I have tested the Response payload in Rest Client?

Tags: rest, powershell, put

Its similar to a question that I asked before but in this scenario, I keep getting 400 malformed even though I have tested the response payload on Rest Client; the link below can direct you to the image with data.

1)  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gJ_och30jQTrcT36RvIbQSmxtqu0zJdD/view?usp=sharing

2) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uZho4-73NRs4gGtXph25nRxUbyH-eq-f/view

Output:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : 400 MalformedCONTENTThe data request is malformed. Required content is missing or empty.Could not acquire data.
At C:\Users\sams\Documents\Reader_Test\2 tRY hMM.ps1:29 char:3
+   Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $url -Headers $headers3 -Body $b ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Current Code:

```
$url = "http://##.###.###.#:####/reader/blink-led"

$headers3 = @{
    "Host"="##.###.###.#:####";
    "Authorization"="Basic dhgageyngixjsklxsfnhjopughNzk5fkswpi"
}     

$body = @'
  {
   "payload": {
          "sensorId": "se:eh:fu:co:c7",
          "blinkCount": 5,
          "blinkOn": 200,
          "blinkOff": 200,
          "countPause": 2,
          "timeout": 5000
      }
  }
  '@

  Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $url -Headers $headers3 -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
```

Why does it say that required content is missing or empty? I have tested the Request payload on the Rest Client and it works. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the verb. Does Postman use `put` or `post`?

Comment: First of all, it is not a poweshell error; it is because of the content that you are passing or the content that is getting accepted by the route. Try posting it normally and see what is the result you are getting. May be the payload that you are passing should be in different format.

Comment: To vonPryz, the rest client, RESTer, accepts put and post. I am not sure about Postman.   To Ranadip,  I have tested the body in different format, and I believe that I am close but stuck at this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the payload is correct, try the following (once with -ContentType "application/json", once wihtout).

```
$uri = "http://##.###.###.#:####/reader/blink-led";

$headers = @{
    Host = "##.###.###.#:####";
    Authorization = "Basic dhgageyngixjsklxsfnhjopughNzk5fkswpi"
};

$body = @{ payload = @{ sensorId = 'se:eh:fu:co:c7'; blinkCount = 5; blinkOn = 200; blinkOff = 200; countPause = 2; timeout = 5000 }} | ConvertTo-Json;

Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType "application/json";
```

Comment: I found the error, thanks to you. I made a minor grammar mistake and I also needed to change my $body section. I was able to get the correct result after correcting the grammar and changing the $body format. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The JSON part is valid, but the `here-string` you are using is not.
There are two  space characters before the final `'@` that you should remove:
If you look at it in the ISE editor, you'll see a red squiggly line and if you hover your mouse over it you wil see:

[image]

```
$body = @'
  {
   "payload": {
          "sensorId": "se:eh:fu:co:c7",
          "blinkCount": 5,
          "blinkOn": 200,
          "blinkOff": 200,
          "countPause": 2,
          "timeout": 5000
      }
  }
'@
```